# Assign each employee from the employee list to all available training in the training list in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm still a newbie to SharePoint and I'm using SharePoint 2013. I'm trying to find the right approach to link each employee in the Employee List to all the available training in the Training List. So if I add or remove training to the Training List, it will reflect the changes for each employee. I came close to solving it but it got so convoluted very quickly.

Employee List:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Employee Number

Training List

- Training Name
- Training Link
- Description
- Suspense Date

Employee Training List

- First Name: Johnny
- Last Name: Good
- Employee Number: 1234
- Training Name: Wash Hands
- Expiration Date: 5/14/2021
- Status: Completed
- First Name: Johnny
- Last Name: Good
- Employee Number: 1234
- Training Name: Wash Face
- Expiration Date:
- Status: Not Completed

Comment: Would you like to say a bit more about how the 3 lists work together? What do you mean by "So if I add or remove training to the Training List, it will reflect the changes for each employee. "?

Comment: Yes. So, when an employee logs in to the training dashboard they will see what training is available and required for them to take. As new training are required, I will add it to the Training List which in turn will appear on the employees training dashboard or if a training is no longer required I will remove it from the Training list, in turn removing it from thier dashboard. Most Training that we do is on an annual basis, some on a quarterly basis, and some very 2 years.

Comment: Right now, I email the employees and remind them what training is available and required ti take, once they're with the training they email me that they have taken the training and I keep track of it. I'm trying to see how I can automate this in SharePoint. I believe if I can pull this off, it will show management that SharePoint is worth the investment and perhaps allow me train in that capacity to build my SharePoint skill sets and turn the organization's task and spreadsheets into SharePont solutions.